# what is the domain or codomain of $\phi$ in $(\phi, N)$-module?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, hodge-theory

In the p-adic Hodge-Tate theory, what does the $\phi$-function in the definition of $(\phi, N)$-module mean?

I mean what is the definition of $\phi$-function here?

I got it that,

> A $\phi-$ module is $K_0=\text{Frac} W(k)$-vector space $D$ with an endomorphism $\phi$ such that, writing $\sigma:K_0 \to K_0$ for Frobenius, the map $\phi$ is called semi-linear. This means that $$ \phi(\lambda x)=\sigma (\lambda) \phi(x)$$, for all $\lambda \in K_0$ and for all $x \in D$.

From the above I know that $\phi$ is an endomorphism.

But what is the domain or codomain of $\phi$ here?

Comment: $\phi$ is a semi-linear endomorphism of $D$ - i.e. a map $D\to D$.

Comment: @Mathmo123, thank you